# Google Analytics Android SDK custom vars not registered/not showing?

Tags: android, google-analytics

So I'm still mucking around with this Google Analytics SDK. According to [this](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-variables-for-your-android.html), I should be able to send custom vars with a visitor scope that include the app version, and the phone model.

Using tracker.getVisitorCustomVar(i) I can see that the information is indeed stored, and the log shows NetWorkRequestUtil/ConstructPageviewRequestPath with a message that contains the custom vars.

But it does not show up in the analytics report along with the other tracking information. I thought I would find it under Visitors->Custom Variables, but that only says

> There is no data for this view.

Where can I see the custom variables? :(

Comment: I don't know the syntax for the Android SDK, but did you make sure to set your Custom Variables *before* your trackPageview/trackEvent call? Custom Variables don't make their own HTTP request.

Comment: Yep. I set the custom vars if the versioncode is higher than the previous or the application has never been run, just after starting the tracker, before calle trackPageView or trackEvent. I can see that the custom vars are appended to the requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How long ago did you incorporate the custom vars? Analytics is not realtime, there can be an --i think-- 24 hour gap?

I'm doing this, and it works for me. I'm assuming you do get other data, so your initialisation and 'dispatching' of the tracker is correct?
You can set your customvar like so (as I imagine you are doing allready).

```
tracker.setCustomVar(TRACK_SLOT_AUTH, TRACK_CVAR_AUTH, isAuth, TRACK_SCOPE_SESSION);
```

(using global vars to be sure not to override already used slots here, but the intention should be clear)

The data shows up under Visitors->Custom Variables

Comment: Yesterday. Does it take longer for the custom vars ot be registered than the pageviews and events? I've got all the latest pageviews and events (I know this, because I am currently the only user).

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But because the vars are dealing not only with page- but also with session- and even visitor-scope, that could be the case. Steps I'd take would be making sure the code is reached, making sure the dispatching and initialising is done exactly the same as with your other analytics, and then wait a bit... If it doesn't work, then you might need to come back and add more code/make a new thread. Bottomline of my answer is at least: your assumption of how it works and where it should show up seem correct ;)

Comment: In my experience, Custom Variables are the slowest data point to process. I've had pageviews register within minutes and custom variables attached to those pageviews take more than 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stop being inpatient and just wait until the weekend has passed. I'll come back and tell you if they've registered then! :)

Comment: There! They're finally there! After 3 days. So anyone having the same problem should just be patient. :)

Comment: Well I've waited 10days and nothing so I'm assuming I've done something else wrong (was using EasyTracker)

Comment: I was correct. Lint had broken my Google Analytics - see here : http://blog.blundell-apps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/

Answer (score 0):

Custom variables have been replaced by Custom Dimensions and Metrics.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/migration#update-methods